# How do I add values of one column which is a foreign key?

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys

I have a table called movies with these attributes:

```
id
title
director
and genre(fk)
```

here genre column is empty.
then I have genre table:

```
genreid
genre
```

Now how do I fill in the genre column in movies table specifying genre for each movie?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UPDATE` statement

```
UPDATE movies 
SET genre = (SELECT id FROM genres WHERE genre = 'action')
WHERE title = 'Batman'
```

Comment: Okay if I do that do i need to connect genreid to  movies as well?

Comment: Also how do I put genre as a foreign key in movies? this is mysql, i used oracle syntax it dint work, do I alter it and column genre, and alter again and then add constraint